# Problem trying to set int variable outside a while loop from inside a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having an issue where I want to run a while loop that will find all the angle brackets an a given line of text but for some reason, the while loop will loop infinitely and the conditions to break it will never be met. The reason for this is because in my code I have an int variable called "leftAngleIndex" which is initially set to 0 I also have another variable called "rightAngleIndex" which is also initially set to 0. After these two variables I have two more variables called "leftAngleBracketLocation" and "rightAngleBracketLocation" these variables both find a "<" or a ">" starting at the index of "leftAngleIndex" or "rightAngleIndex" so 0 in this case.

Now the issue is when we get to the end of the while loop I want to set values of "leftAngleIndex" equal to "leftAngleBracketLocation" and the same thing for "rightAngleIndex". By doing this we will be able to find all of the "<" and ">" in our line of text. And once there is no more "<" or ">" then are loop should break because the value of "leftAngleBracketLocation" will be set to -1.

This is not the case however and for some reason I can not set "rightAngleIndex" equal to rightAngleBracketLocation and the same thing for "leftAngleIndex" I can not set it equal to "leftAngleBracketLocation". And that is why I am here I am not sure why I am not able to set these values.

```
/**
 * 
 * This method takes in our final phrase and replaces Non-Terminals until all the Non-Terminals have been replaced
 * 
 * @param phrase
 * @return final phrase
 */
private static String buildPhrase(String phrase) {
    // Create a string builder for the final phrase and for any Non-Terminals we find.
    StringBuilder finalPhrase = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder NonTerminal = new StringBuilder();

    int start = 0;
    int leftAngleIndex = 0;
    int rightAngleIndex = 0;
    int end = phrase.length();

    // Will find index of the current "<" bracket.
    int leftAngleBracketLocation = phrase.indexOf("<", leftAngleIndex);

    // Will find the index of the current ">" bracket.
    int rightAngleBracketLocation = phrase.indexOf(">", rightAngleIndex);

    // Will find all of the Non-Terminal values in our phrase and then replace them with terminal values.
    while (leftAngleBracketLocation != -1) {
        // This will append everything up to the first Non-Terminal.
        finalPhrase.append(phrase, start, leftAngleBracketLocation);

        // This will append the non-terminal and tell us what non-terminal we have so we can find the coresponding terminal value for it.
        NonTerminal.append(phrase, leftAngleBracketLocation, rightAngleBracketLocation);

        
        // This will allow us to keep finding non-terminals unitl there is no more non-terminals.
        leftAngleIndex = leftAngleBracketLocation;
        rightAngleIndex = rightAngleBracketLocation;
    }

    // This will append the rest of our phrase.
    finalPhrase.append(phrase, rightAngleBracketLocation, end);

    return finalPhrase.toString();
}
```

Comment: actually, you do that, but you never change the value of leftAngleBracketLocation. (same for right) in your while loopµ

Comment: You don't use `leftAngleIndex` or `rightAngleIndex` at all in your loop.

Comment: With infinite while loops you always have to look for the break condition. In your case you are checking for the `leftAngleBracketLocation` but this is never re-assigned in your loop. This also looks like a perfect case for using a debugger, then you'd see directly the values and what your code is doing.

Comment: Are you expecting values of local variables to persist between calls to `buildPhrase`?

Comment: @Stultuske but I shouldn't need to change the value of "leftAngleBracketLocation" or "rightAngleBracketLocation" should I? Since they are doing the same thing every time they are called. The only thing that needs to change is the value of "leftAngleIndex" and the same for the right correct because that is the index which we start our search for the angle brackets from.

Comment: @Alex of course you should! As long as that value doesn't get updated, you'll never be able to get out of that loop.